# Posting on a user's Facebook wall using C#

Tags: c#, facebook

I am creating a third-party (C# console) application to post status on my (current user) Facebook wall. I've done the same for an application (where I was using the same console application to post on application's wall).

I'm using the [Facebook C# SDK][1] API and getting exception at `faceookClient.Post("/me/feed",arguments)` function:

> An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.`

Do I need to get user access token for accomplishing it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You will need to get a valid access token and pass it when you post

Comment: i ve read the manual n m done trying everything, cause m working on console application so cant use web browser to redirect my user for authentication, n there is nothing in documentation to get user access token-page access token using console application(without redirection) in case i ve missed some reading, do tell me, i l really appreciate. thanks in advance